# springboot autowiring @Repository inside of @Configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple spring boot application in which I have a jpa repository object which i want to autowire inside an `@Configuration` class like below.

```
@Configuration
public class Appconfig {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(OctopusPropertiesRepository repo) {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer property = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Map<String,Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        List<OctopusProperties> loadedSettings = repo.findAll();
        loadedSettings.forEach(entry -> props.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        mutablePropertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("custom", props));
        property.setPropertySources(mutablePropertySources);
        return property;
    }
}
```

And here is the `@Repository` class

```
@Repository
public interface OctopusPropertiesRepository extends JpaRepository<OctopusProperties, Long> {
}
```

And I get following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.app.OctopusPropertiesRepository]
```

If i don't make that configuration and boot app successfully i see from the actuator that bean is available. What is the problem here? why I can't wire `@Repository` inside `@Configuration`.

**P.S.** These two java files are under same folder: `com.example.app`

**P.P.S.** Eclipse view of my project:

[image]

Comment: include class which is scanning for components. Please also include packages into listings. Probably main class?

Comment: Main class is in root package, and all other classes in the same package. I think its somewhat related with the timing, because spring is generating this bean if i dont use this configuration.

Comment: If you add a simple member, like below, in the configuration class does Spring find it? @Autowired OctopusPropertiesRepository octopusPropertiesRepository

Comment: no, i tried it but no change :(

Comment: @luboskrnac I have added the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @PostConstruct.

```
@Autowired PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer property;


@Autowired OctopusPropertiesRepository repo;


   @PostConstruct
    public  void onInit() {

        Map<String,Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        List<OctopusProperties> loadedSettings = repo.findAll();
        loadedSettings.forEach(entry -> props.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        mutablePropertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("custom", props));
        property.setPropertySources(mutablePropertySources);

    }
```

Comment: don't you mean @PostConstruct?

Comment: I do not know if you need to create the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Bean instance manually or if Spring boot creates it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

According to the @Bean javadoc:

```
BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods
Special consideration must be taken for @Bean methods that return Spring 
BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BFPP) types. Because BFPP objects must be    
instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can interfere with
processing of annotations such as @Autowired, @Value, and @PostConstruct
within @Configuration classes. To avoid these lifecycle issues, mark BFPP
returning @Bean methods as static. For example: 

 @Bean
 public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() {
     // instantiate, configure and return ppc ...
 }


By marking this method as static, it can be invoked without causing 
instantiation of its declaring @Configuration class, thus avoiding the above-
mentioned lifecycle conflicts. Note however that static @Bean methods will not   
be enhanced for scoping and AOP semantics as mentioned above. This works out
in BFPP cases, as they are not typically referenced by other @Bean methods. As
a reminder, a WARN-level log message will be issued for any non-static @Bean
methods having a return type assignable to BeanFactoryPostProcessor.
```

So according to this, your `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()` should be static.

**Edit:**
Sorry for the late edit.
I don't think you can use Hibernate repository here, because `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` gets instantiated before any dependency needed for hibernate and jpa.
Perhaps you could use JdbcTemplate here, at least that worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class Appconfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer property = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Map<String, Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        List<OctopusProperties> loadedSettings = getAll();
        loadedSettings.forEach(entry -> props.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        mutablePropertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("custom", props));
        property.setPropertySources(mutablePropertySources);
        return property;
    }

    @Bean
    public static DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }

    private List<OctopusProperties> getAll() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
        List<OctopusProperties> all = jdbcTemplate.query("select id,key_column,value_column from octopus_properties",
                new RowMapper<OctopusProperties>() {
                    @Override
                    public OctopusProperties mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        OctopusProperties op = new OctopusProperties();
                        op.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                        op.setKey(rs.getString("key_column"));
                        op.setValue(rs.getString("value_column"));
                        return op;
                    }
                });
        return all;
    }

}
```

Please note, that I've used MySQL here, so the datasource is configured accordingly.

Comment: good points, I did not know the mentioned parts and tried with hope but still same error :(

Comment: yeah, tried it too, same error for me as well, let me investage a bit, I'll get back to you

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem is addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10539417/2815219) question

Is it permissible to change your `AppConfig` class like this?

```
@Configuration
public class Appconfig {

    @Autowired
    private OctopusPropertiesRepository repo;

    @Bean
    public  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer property = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Map<String,Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        List<OctopusProperties> loadedSettings = repo.findAll();
        loadedSettings.forEach(entry -> props.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        mutablePropertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("custom", props));
        property.setPropertySources(mutablePropertySources);
        return property;
    }
}
```

Do revert if this solution works or not.